# Spring Boot sync caching with caffeine does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, caffeine

I'm using Spring Boot `1.5.12.RELEASE`, with caffeine `2.6.2` as caching provider.

I have a method in one of my services:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = [CacheService.MY_CACHE_NAME], sync = true)
fun fetchThing(id: Int, at: OffsetDateTime?): Thing? {
    LOGGER.debug("################### $id $at #############")

    // some network operation

    LOGGER.debug("################### $id $at IS DONE #############")

    return thing
}
```

I'd expect to see the first log only once, but if I call `fetchThing` again before the first call resolved, the value is computed two times:

```
09:18:34.657 [XNIO-2 task-11] DEBUG c.a.n.i.thing.ThingService - ################### 3140 null #############
09:18:34.673 [XNIO-2 task-12] DEBUG c.a.n.i.thing.ThingService - ################### 3140 null #############
09:18:36.025 [XNIO-2 task-11] DEBUG c.a.n.i.thing.ThingService - ################### 3140 null IS DONE #############
09:18:36.030 [XNIO-2 task-12] DEBUG c.a.n.i.thing.ThingService - ################### 3140 null IS DONE #############
```

If I call this function again I don't see any logs so the caching is working.

So it seems that `sync` is not working.
Am I missing something?

EDIT:
main class annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ElastiCacheAutoConfiguration::class])
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
class Application
```

Comment: Do you have `@EnableCaching` on you main class?

Comment: @ShanuGupta yes, updated question

Comment: Maybe try reproducing in [spring-boot-sample-cache](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache) with different Boot versions, to see if it was a bug.

Comment: seems `Caffeine` does not support `sync`. from `@Cacheable` doc: `actual cache provider that you are using may not support it in a synchronized fashion`

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi. If that was the case, Ben Manes (creator of Caffeine) would have mentioned it in the previous comment.

Comment: @Ritesh, agree with you, I later tested it with Caffeine and `sync` works fine. need to remove my previous comment

Comment: @Vasiliy Sarzhynskyi Which version of springboot and caffeine did works fine for you?

Comment: @JihunNo I tested it with spring-boot `2.1.4.RELEASE` and caffeine `2.6.2`

Comment: @VasiliySarzhynskyi Thank you. I'd better to upgrade boot from 1 to 2. : )

Answer (score 0):

It is ridiculous, but... try to change the cache name.

I've just had the same problem and had no idea what's wrong in my config. So I've changed the name of the cache - it magically worked. So silly...